# Compiler issues with Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I’m actually trying to create a game with swift and I have a bug that I can’t figure how to fix it :

```
CollisionWithBullet(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, Bullet: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
   }
    else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PLayer) ||
        (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.PLayer) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Enemy)){

            CollisionWithPerson(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode , Person: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

            CollisionWithBullet(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, Bullet: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)
```

I got the following message:

> 'SKNode?' is not convertible to 'SKSpriteNode'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast.

I have searched on several website the solution and I have tried to change `as` to `as!` and to `as?` but nothing works.

I would thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What's the method signature of CollisionWithXXX.

Answer (score 0):

This means that one of your sprites were initialized as SKNodes which is meant to hold SKSpriteNodes.

You tried to downcast it to SKSpriteNode but you are not supposed to do that as they are not meant to display any images.

The fix would be to initialize them as SKSpriteNodes instead of SKNode.

From the apple documentation

> The SKNode class is the fundamental building block of most Sprite Kit
>   content. The SKNode class doesn’t draw any visual content. Its primary
>   role is to provide baseline behavior that the other node classes use.
>   All visual elements in a Sprite Kit-based game are drawn using
>   predefined SKNode subclasses.